# Files needed to deploy delphi 2010 dbxpress application

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm having trouble deploying my delphi application. It uses dbxpress to access mysql 5.1 database. When i run the application from another computer, an error occurs. I've already included the midaslib.dll in my application and copied the dbxmys.dll and libmysql.dll in the same folder as my application.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a connection with the ping command? Can you make a connection to the database itself? Just with the command prompt. Not with Delphi.

Maybe a firewall is blocking or the remote user is not authorized.